# Is there a way to execute a script after clicking on list ,from the text input element,  of stored values 

Tags: jquery, html

I want to execute a jquery script that will fade a `<label for='username'>` after someone selects an entry from stored input values given by the browser (the values that are given when autocomplete='on') from the `<input name='username' type='text'>` element.

Is there any way to check if user picked a selection from a stored input values ??

.. I already though of an ugly solution to this when i check if text input is empty whenever user presses a key or mouse button but i would like a nicer solution

**Update:**
I found out that the solution i had in mind doesnt actually work --but here is the pseudocode anyways:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
mouseup(function(){
  if(!isWhitespace($("#username")){
   //blur the label
  }
 //same function for keyup() 
  function isWhitespace(elem){
           $elemCont = elem.val().replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
                            if ($elemCont === '') {
                                // element contained all whitespace
                                elem.val('');
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                // element has real content
                                elem.val($elemCont); //free element of leading/trailing whitespace  
                                return false; 
                            }
       }
}

}
```

Comment: How about posting what you came up with so we don't duplicate your efforts?

Comment: What exactly is a `hint given by the browser`? Tooltip? Or is it part of your HTML?

Comment: by hint i mean the window that pops up when you have entered values before to a field with a similar name. Like you have made an account called "Freelancer" before and you making another account when you double click on the input text field the freelancer will pop up in the list.

Comment: its a function in every browser and not my own code *

Comment: @Xitcod13 Your question references a lot of things that you havent explained: Hints, popup windows, accounts... You should give more context for what is happening. As it is, I have too many questions to begin to help you. Glad you found a solution though.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity let me know if there is anything you guys are still confused about. And let me know if you find a better or even different solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it in a semi nice manner. 
because the list of stored input values that appears is not part of `$(document)` and i couldnt find the name for the element (i dont think it has a name you can just turn it off with `autocoplete="off"`) it was challenging but possible.
I simply made a function that executes every time you hover in to the document

```
$(document).hover(function() {

if(!isWhitespace($("#inputId")){
//blur label
}


},function(){});
```

This works
even when you move your mouse out of the browser and use the keyboard to select an item from the stored value list.

If anybody finds a better solution feel free to respond